# Checking/ moving files based on regex

Tags: regex, shell, osx-mountain-lion

Im trying to write a shell script on a mac that will move raw camera files.  These files need to be named very specifically.  I have the regex to check the file names against, I've just had zero luck making it work correctly.  What does work correctly is looking inside a specific folder for a folder name containing the raw files and getting a list of the files.

Im also trying to error check.  I've been trying to use if statements to check the filenames with.

I'm needing help writing the if statement to check if the files are named correctly.

I would greatly appreciate any help as I'm completely stuck at this point.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

product="^[A-Z0-9]{2}\w[A-Z0-9]{6,7}\w[A-Z]{1}\.(EIP)"

#folder of files to check
folder_files="$(ls -d *)"

#just get a list of everything .EIP
FILES_LIST="$(ls *.EIP)"

for file in $FILES_LIST; do
#something with $file

echo $file

#where im having the trouble 
If (grep or find based on $product)
then

    #move files, create log

else

    #move files to an error folder for renaming

fi

done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly brackets are part of extended regular extension (ERE) syntax,
not basic regular expression (BRE) syntax so we need to use "egrep". I also took the liberty of removing the brackets from your regex as I see that you are looking for files ending in `.EIP` so this leaves us with:

```
product="^[A-Z0-9]{2}\w[A-Z0-9]{6,7}\w[A-Z]{1}\.EIP"
```

We will also need to change the `$IFS` variable, as it's used by the FOR loop to determine the field separator. By default the field separator is set to the space character, which does not work great for strings where the field separator can be part of the string(i.e. if the filenames contain spaces). We store the current value of IFS to a variable and we set the IFS:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

When we are done we are going to restore the IFS to its original value:

```
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Now we will pipe the filename to egrep and filter using our regex while redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`. The `$?` variable will let us know if our egrep returned a match.

```
echo $file | egrep $product &>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
  echo "$file - acceptable"
else 
  echo "$file - not acceptable"
fi
```

Here is how the complete script looks like (tested on mountain lion):

```
#!/bin/bash 

product="^[A-Z0-9]{2}\w[A-Z0-9]{6,7}\w[A-Z]{1}\.EIP"

FILES_LIST="$(ls *.EIP)"

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

for file in $FILES_LIST; do
  echo $file | egrep $product &>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "$file - acceptable"
    #move files, create log
  else 
    echo "$file - not acceptable"
    #move files to an error folder for renaming
  fi
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS

exit 0
```

Note you can check for compliance to *N* naming conventions by using multiple blocks of `if` statements and only one `else` condition at the very end as shown below:

```
for file in $FILES_LIST; do

  echo $file | egrep $regex1 &>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "$file - accepted by regex1"
    #move files, create log
    continue
  fi

  echo $file | egrep $regex2 &>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "$file - accepted by regex2"
    #move files, create log
    continue
  fi

  echo $file | egrep $regexN &>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "$file - accepted by regexN"
    #move files, create log
  else 
    echo "$file - not acceptable"
    #move files to an error folder for renaming
  fi
done
```

Note the use of `continue` as it resumes the iteration of the `for` loop, allowing for only a single action to be taken per file (think of filenames compliant to more than 1 naming convention)

Comment: works beautifully, slight caveat.  `echo $file | egrep "$product" &>/dev/null` had to put " around $product.  I  added the code the script, and everything errored out.  Went to a regex checker.  The regex was fine.  So I removed the var `$product` and replace with the entire regex and it worked.   Any idea why that is?   this worked amazingly well, and fast thank you very much.  Also thank you very much for explaining it so well.

Comment: 1 other quick question, this will not work if I `elif` instead of `else`.  there are multiple types of filename structures we use.  I could just not use the `else` and try another `echo` to `egrep` yes?

Comment: hey @d1g1talphyre, have a look at the updated answer. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain that macosx uses gnu find, but I'm betting that it does.

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -ireg ${myregex} -print
```

The filename to match includes the *entire* path, so you need to start your regex with ^./ and  end with $

rather than an if, I'd prefer to write the entire thing as two xargs.

```
# first move the good stuff to its destination
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -ireg ${myregex} -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 mv {} ../good-dir/
# anything remaining is bad
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 sh -c 'echo "bad file name: {}" > /var/log/whatever.log; mv {} ../bad-dir/'
```